# Pass one table field as a parameter to another table in SSRS report

Tags: reporting-services, sql-server-2008-r2, ssrs-2008

I am new in SSRS report. I am using SQL Server 2008 R2. I have created one SSRS report which have two tables, First table has only one column and second table has multiple columns. Now I want to pass first table column as a parameter to the second table to get result for second table.

```
First Table:
Column: Assined_To

Second Table:
Columns: Assined_To,
         Status,
         Start_date,
         End_Date
```

As per first table "Assined_to" value, I have to show second table.
I have done lots of googling for this but did not get any solution.
link I got:
"http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/c7e4d614-c4e2-4013-88c0-6aaa947af34f/want-to-pass-one-report-column-values-to-another-report-as-a-parameter-ssrs?forum=sqlreportingservices"

Can we do it?
Please give your valuable suggestion for the same. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you looking to populate the second table once, when the report is opened, or populate the second table by clicking on a row value in the first table?

Answer (score 0):

you'll want to use cascading parameters to do this (if I'm reading your explanation correctly)
 Firstly, on the report data section expand parameters, right click and Add Parameter

if the column has a fixed value, you can just assign it there - if it has multiple values, under "default values" you can set it to "get results from query"
 make sure that you allow multiple results if you want to bring them all in - it will give you a comma delimited string to that parameter

also remember, that it's returning a string, so to compare those values you'll need to use the IN operator, not equals... and NOT IN isn't an option in SSRS - so that requires some clever workarounds.

I do this all the time in SSRS because you can't declare variables in the SQL - it's obnoxious sometimes, but it works
 let me know if this helps or if you have any other questions!

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by NOT IN being unavailable in SSRS or being unable to declare variables in the SQL. Could you elaborate on those points?

Comment: in SQL you can declare variables in your query to hold data, but the Declare function isn't available in query designer - they intend you to do all of this with report level parameters. Also, IN is a comparative operator, like finding a substring match in a string - but you can't do NOT IN, the opposite of this (you never know when you need to NOT something). That's all, but it doesn't sound like something you need to worry about at the moment

Comment: I think I disagree with your assessments, which is why I'm asking.  You have NOT IN available to you in T-SQL and can use it in SSRS (you just make sure your query is written appropriately). I guess I don't consider the cascading parameters to be a workaround. I think perhaps it is a difference of semantics of defining your variable in SSRS and then using it in your SQL vs defining it in your SQL. But I believe you can accomplish the same goal with what is available in SSRS.

Comment: NOT IN is not an available operator in SSRS, unfortunately - there are, however, logical workarounds when designing the query. You also cannot use DECLARE in query designer in SSRS, so if you're going to generate variables you're relegated to report level parameters

Comment: Ah, I think I see what you are saying. NOT IN is not listed as an operator when building expressions in SSRS. That's true. But you can use NOT IN in your SQL statements to retrieve data from a source. I tend to only pull the data I need and therefore only need it in my SQL Statements rather than an operator. Since SSRS will evaluate the data for a given cell or single parameter value at a time, I've never found a need for an operator to perform a NOT IN function. You can use stored procs that use DECLARE or use the SSRS params to accomplish the same goal as declaring a variable in SQL.